# MySQL SELECT query seems to skip spaces

Tags: php, mysql, string, select, space

I'm a beginner with PHP and mySQL and I'm using it for my project. I sort of have a problem with my query.

This is my code:

```
    $doctname = mysql_query("SELECT name_of_doctor FROM {$table} WHERE department_no = '{$_REQUEST['deptno']}'");
    $doctnamerow = mysql_fetch_row($doctname);

    do
    {
        foreach ($doctnamerow as $cell)
        {
            $doctnamerowvalue = $cell;
        }
    } while ($doctnamerow = mysql_fetch_row($doctname));
```

So the problem I have is that if the doctor's name has a space between it (e.g "AJ Ramos") then it seems to skip the space and just returns "AJ" and not the surname. How do I do this? Thanks =)

edit:

Silly me, It was just an error with my code, I was using $doctnamerowvalue as a value=$doctnamerow for one of my text boxes and forgot to put double quotes, which resulted in value=doctor name and not value="doctor name". Sorry

Comment: `?deptno='; DROP TABLE doctors;--`

Comment: How did you determine that your return value is truncated (please show the code). Also, what's the point of your `foreach` loop?

Comment: What's your table structure?

Comment: @RandomSeed thank you for reminding me to determine if my return value is truncated. It was simply an error with my syntax. I was using $doctnamerowvalue as a value for one of my text boxes, and forgot to put double quotes which resulted in value=doctor name and not value="doctor name". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Flash Code Review:**

- `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO.
- Your code is wide open to SQL injection
- `$doctornamerowvalue` is overwritten on every iteration
- the `foreach` you are doing is pointless.
- variable names are poorly chosen.

**Here it is refactored:**

```
// do these in a config file !!!
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';host=localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // if you want to use associative arrays

// here is the refactored code
$query = "SELECT name_of_doctor FROM `{$table}` WHERE department_no = :deptno";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':deptno' => $_REQUEST['deptno']));
$doctors = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($doctors as $doctor) {
     echo $doctor['name_of_doctor'] . '<br>';
}
```

**Related to your 'bug'**

- Check the table structure and data. It's possible that the field contains only the surname, and there is another field that contains the name.
- Check the table length - maybe it's too small, so the string is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "your sql syntax";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$array_of_things = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array_of_things[] = $row['table_column_name'];
}

foreach($array_of_things as $val) {
    echo $val; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

used this :

```
$doctname = mysql_query("SELECT name_of_doctor FROM {$table} WHERE department_no = '{$_REQUEST['deptno']}'");
$doctnamerow = mysql_fetch_row($doctname);


while ($raw = mysql_fetch_row($doctname)) {
echo $raw['name_of_doctor'];
}
```